# opera browser flip my arabic code

Tags: button, opera, arabic, right-to-left

i made this simple buttons in Arabic Language (right to left language) and it works fine with all browsers except Opera, it looks flipped!

this is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gtd52/1/

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
<a class="download_button1" href="#">رابط التحميل</a>
<a class="download_button1" href="#">رابط التحميل</a>
<a class="download_button1" href="#">رابط التحميل</a>
<a class="download_button1" href="#">رابط التحميل</a>
</p>
```

and it appears in opera like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/13qyK.png

so.. what can i do to correct it?

Comment: Looks fine using Opera 20.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your original fiddle, just add `display:inline-block;` to `.download_button1` and it will work as expected. see results on [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/fcad3634fe61162b7b070aec978cbfc1513ace7c)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the first line as follows:

`<p style="text-align:center;" dir="rtl">`

and it should work.

Comment: thanks, it worked with "just arabic text",
but when i write a number with it, the problem still appear
http://jsfiddle.net/gtd52/2/

Comment: No need for RTL at all, as the style has no directional difference.